# Add a border and change border color of a marker in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, web-mapping, markers

I want to add a border color to the icons in OpenLayers. I also, want to be able to change the color of this border depending on the attribute of the marker. Is there any easy way to do this?
The code below allows you to click the icon and make a border color appear. However, I want the color to be their from the beginning and not depend on the clicks. Also, I want it to change depending on the variable. If anyone has any idea please let me know.

```
class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  map:Map;
  iconVectorSource: VectorSource;
  iconVectorLayer: VectorLayer;

  iconArr: Feature[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  this.map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',  
      center: [114.190750, 22.339914],
      zoom: 12,
      minZoom: 12,
    }),

    layers:[
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
      }),
    ]
  });
  this.addIcons();
  this.addSelect();

  }
  public addIcons(){
    let icon1 = new Feature({
      geometry: new Point([114.190750, 22.339914]),
      imgSrc: 'assets/purple.png',
    });

    icon1.set('style',this.createStyle(icon1.get('imgSrc'), undefined));

    this.iconArr.push(icon1);
    this.iconVectorSource = new VectorSource({
      features: this.iconArr,
      wrapX: false,
    });
    //creates a layer and use the source in the layer
    this.iconVectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: this.iconVectorSource,
      style: function(feature){
        return feature.get('style');
      },
    });
    this.map.addLayer(this.iconVectorLayer);

  }

  public addSelect(){
    var select = new Select({
      style: function(feature) {
        var image = feature.get('style').getImage().getImage();

          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          var activeColor = "red"; //set border color
          var dArr = [-1,-1, 0,-1, 1,-1, -1,0, 1,0, -1,1, 0,1, 1,1], // offset array
              s = 2,  // thickness scale
              i = 0,  // iterator
              x = 2,  // final x position
              y = 2;  // final y position

          //set new canvas dimentions adjusted for border
          canvas.width = image.width + s + s;
          canvas.height = image.height + s + s;

          // draw images at offsets from the array scaled by s
          for(; i < dArr.length; i += 2)
          ctx.drawImage(image, x + dArr[i]*s, y + dArr[i+1]*s);

          // fill with color
          ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
          ctx.fillStyle = activeColor;
          ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

          // draw original image in normal mode
          ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
          ctx.drawImage(image, x, y,image.width, image.height);

          //create new openlayers icon style from canvas
          return new Style({
              image: new Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
              crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
              src: undefined,
              img: canvas,
              imgSize: canvas ? [canvas.width, canvas.height] : undefined
            }))
          });

      }
    });
    this.map.addInteraction(select);
  }

  public createStyle(src, img) {
    return new Style({
      image: new Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        src: src,
        img: img,
        imgSize: img ? [img.width, img.height] : undefined
      }))
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not changing style on clicks you wouldn't need a Select interaction.  Move the `activeColor` definition outside the function (you will have some other code which changes it) then inside the layer style function check if the color has changed (the feature will need to store color as well as style) and change the style to match the new color if necessary.

```
class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  map:Map;
  iconVectorSource: VectorSource;
  iconVectorLayer: VectorLayer;
  activeColor: string;

  iconArr: Feature[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  this.map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',  
      center: [114.190750, 22.339914],
      zoom: 12,
      minZoom: 12,
    }),

    layers:[
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
      }),
    ]
  });
  this.activeColor = 'red'; //set border color
  this.addIcons();

  }
  public addIcons(){
    let icon1 = new Feature({
      geometry: new Point([114.190750, 22.339914]),
      imgSrc: 'assets/purple.png',
    });

    icon1.set('style',this.createStyle(icon1.get('imgSrc'), undefined));

    this.iconArr.push(icon1);
    this.iconVectorSource = new VectorSource({
      features: this.iconArr,
      wrapX: false,
    });
    //creates a layer and use the source in the layer
    this.iconVectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: this.iconVectorSource,
      style: function(feature) {
        if (feature.get('color') !== this.activeColor) {

          var image = feature.get('style').getImage().getImage();

          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          var dArr = [-1,-1, 0,-1, 1,-1, -1,0, 1,0, -1,1, 0,1, 1,1], // offset array
              s = 2,  // thickness scale
              i = 0,  // iterator
              x = 2,  // final x position
              y = 2;  // final y position

          //set new canvas dimentions adjusted for border
          canvas.width = image.width + s + s;
          canvas.height = image.height + s + s;

          // draw images at offsets from the array scaled by s
          for(; i < dArr.length; i += 2)
          ctx.drawImage(image, x + dArr[i]*s, y + dArr[i+1]*s);

          // fill with color
          ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
          ctx.fillStyle = this.activeColor;
          ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

          // draw original image in normal mode
          ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
          ctx.drawImage(image, x, y,image.width, image.height);

          //create new openlayers icon style from canvas
          var newStyle = new Style({
              image: new Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
              crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
              src: undefined,
              img: canvas,
              imgSize: canvas ? [canvas.width, canvas.height] : undefined
            }))
          });

          feature.set('style', newStyle);
          feature.set('color', this.activeColor);

        }
        return feature.get('style');
      },
    });
    this.map.addLayer(this.iconVectorLayer);
  }

  public createStyle(src, img) {
    return new Style({
      image: new Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        src: src,
        img: img,
        imgSize: img ? [img.width, img.height] : undefined
      }))
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to be working, the icon is not in the place where it is supposed to be. Nothing in that position. 

if i just use 
  style: function(feature){
        return feature.get('style')
}
this shows an icon but when i add the code above no icon can be seen on the map.

Comment: Also, different icon have different border color not a fixed color (this.activecolor)

Comment: You said you wanted the color to change depending on the variable.  If you have code which changes the value of activecolor the color will change.

Comment: Here is working code https://codesandbox.io/s/icon-negative-mpi4m  There were two problems (1) you cannot update until the original icon has loaded and (2) you must save the origin icon, otherwise your code will draw a new border outside the earlier border.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. There is just one last thing, i will be updating the icon's border depending on what i get from server. This means that different icon will have different border but with this code all the icons will have the same border. How do i solve this issue ?

Comment: If each feature has its own active color you could replace the single activeColor variable with one for the feature using `feature.set('activeColor', color_from_server)` and `feature.get('activeColor')`

Comment: I am using angular to create the map, I used the same code as yours and the icon still disappears. For some reason when i print the canvas we have different canvas
Your canvas:
<canvas width="36" height="52"></canvas>
My canvas:
<canvas width="4" height="4"></canvas>

Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: please check it here, it is the same as your code but the icon disappears for some reason.
https://codesandbox.io/embed/exciting-johnson-g04b2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You are trying to make changes before the icon has been loaded.  I've added a test for `image.width > 0` to prevent that https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-worker-n3ydn

Comment: Hey, When i try to add border for other icons it actually colors the inside of the icon and not only the border.How do i solve this issue?

Comment: If there is transparency inside the icon it would be filled if you use `fillRect()`  You could try using `strokeRect()` instead (also setting `strokeStyle` and `lineWidth`) but you would need to draw a more precise outline.

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt work.

Comment: How do i make a more precise outline ?

Comment: I tried to increase the thickness scale, after a certain scale the border looks weird and is not even all around. How do i fix this ??